# Show attached media image if no thumbnail image detected

Tags: attachments, media, thumbnails

I use the

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ){}
```

to check if the post have  thumbnail image, but this

```
echo get_attached_media('image', $post->ID);
```

displays the word

```
Array
```

I need to show the attached image

Comment: thanx>>>@Pieter Goosen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `get_attached_media()`, you can try for example:

```
if( has_post_thumbnail() )
{
    the_post_thumbnail();
}
else
{
    $imgs = get_attached_media( 'image' );

    if( count( $imgs ) > 0 )
    {
        $img = array_shift( $imgs );
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $img->ID, 'thumbnail' );
    }
}
```

to display one of the attached images, if there's no `featured` image available for the current post.

Notice that you can't use `echo` to show the content of an *array*, only for a *scalar* variable.

Comment: yes it is .....  WORK!!!! thanx dud

Comment: you're welcome, glad to hear it worked for you.